# There are many spam suggestions on one post last time

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, spam

I noticed very quite a large amount of anonymous spam edits suggested on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100817/avast-reporting-virus-when-browsing-to-so-question/101013#101013) post last time. The spam itself is actually different, but I don't think that is just a coincidence - since oct 19 I noticed 9 such suggestions and sure that there are more. Before oct 19 I didn't notice lots of spam suggestions to this post (also there were a single spam suggestion in sep 28, **again** on this post).

Maybe it is possible to take any actions against it?

Comment: Yep. Fave it and if an edit goes through, alert the mods there are reviewers waiting to be sternly talked to.

Comment: 44 spam edits rejected so far, [first one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/31395) appears to be just a test of some sort.

Comment: This may be a desired state of things, according to [Tim Post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237055/): "If you suggest an edit to a post that has a certain number of edits rejected as spam recently and _then that edit is rejected as spam_ - we deal you a blocking penalty in the spam system. In other words, known targets dynamically become honeypots."

Comment: Was just thinking this myself having done a few spam reviews on that thread. Ideally, there'd be a way to *lock* an entire thread - edits/comments/answers - even if just from anonymous users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have declined many of those edits as spam myself.

After a while of the suggested spam edits, or maybe even with the help of your question, the user [Infinite Recursion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/245167/infinite-recursion) left a comment on that post, stating something like "STOP SPAMMING THIS ANSWER" or something.

EDIT: here's a screen shot of @inf informing Taverners of this :

[image]

Apparently, the spammer(s) were scared off and never returned to that post. Some others seem to disagree with that assertion and say they aren't spamming that anymore, since the question has been deleted, so it's not possible to suggest an edit on that answer anymore.

So this issue no longer exists for this particular answer you linked to, since the answer no longer exists.

Comment: Yup, it was nuked by Shog who probably got fed up by all those spam edits. :-)

Comment: No longer an issue, so accepting.